# DropDown transparente com bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Bom dia, eu tenho um menu dropdown(código abaixo, que usa bootstrap, como eu faço pra deixar o fundo transparente, visto que por default ele é branco ?
Em qual atributo do CSS eu mexo ?

```
<html>
    <head>
    <!---- importações -->
    </head>

    <body>
    <li class="dropdown nav-item">
                  <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link js-scroll-trigger">Clientes</a>
                   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li class="nav-item">  <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#"> Depoimentos </a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item">  <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#">2ª via do boleto </a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item">  <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#">Atendimento </a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item">  <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#">Seja um revendedor </a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Oi Slyfer, nesse caso tu apenas pode acrescentar mais uma classe no dropdown-menu, "transparent" e fazer a alteração no estilo ou mesmo podendo acrescentar na variables.
no caso se fazer no seu estilo e não souber criar na variable faça .dropdown-menu.transparent {} assim não é necessário usar !important se caso a cor branca estiver no li use .dropdown-menu.transparent .nav-item {}

Comment: Entendi, obrigado!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Altere a propriedade `background-color` da classe `.dropdown-menu` usando a notação `rgba` se quiser deixar semi-transparente alterando o canal alpha:

```css
body{
   background: yellow !important;
}

.dropdown-menu{
   /* metade transparente: alpha = .5 */
   background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5) !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<li class="dropdown nav-item">
   <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link js-scroll-trigger">Clientes</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
         <li class="nav-item">  <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#"> Depoimentos </a></li>
         <li class="nav-item">  <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#">2ª via do boleto </a></li>
         <li class="nav-item">  <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#">Atendimento </a></li>
         <li class="nav-item">  <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#">Seja um revendedor </a></li>
     </ul>
 </li>
```

Se quiser **totalmente transparente**, coloque o valor `transparent`:

```
.dropdown-menu{
   background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

> Caso não queira alterar a classe nativa, siga o que informa a resposta
>   do @Renan Osorio.

Comment: Caso queira evitar usar o !important apenas acrescente mais uma classe no dropdown-menu dessa forma não precisará sobrepor a força e sim fará pela nova classe.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Tente isso,

```
.dropdown-menu {
    background-color: transparent;
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Esse é um exemplo, mas se possível, crie uma classe separada para adicionar o background-color: transparent; para nao afetar o codigo nativo do bootstrap.

Comment: Funcionou também, obrigado!!